# clojure - project euler primes timing out

Tags: clojure

I am trying to solve the project euler problem that asks you to supply the nth prime number, e.g. the 6th prime number is 13.

My code looks like this:

```
(ns scratch.core
  (require [clojure.string :as str :only (split-lines join)]))

(def t "2\n3\n6")

(defn work [input]
  (let [lines (map read-string (str/split-lines input))]
    (letfn [(is-prime? [n]
              (or
               (= n 2)
               (empty? (filter #(= 0 (mod n %)) (range 2 (inc (Math/sqrt n)))))))
            (parse-primes [[x & xs]]
              (prn (last (take x (filter #(is-prime? %) (iterate inc 2)))))
              (if (seq xs)
                (recur xs)))]
       (parse-primes (rest lines)))))

(work t)
```

The `(def t 2\n3\n6)` is only my test data, I don't know what the actual number the program that verifies the answer does although the maximum is 10^4.

I'm surprised this code times out, can anyone suggest what the potential bottlenecks might be?

Comment: Works well in my environment. Anyway, you're trying too much in your function `work`, parsing string, printing result, etc. You'd better to split out the side-effects and non-core logics from your function. For example, you can pass the argument as sequence other than string, which makes unnecessary parsing string. And instead of printing out the result, return the value in your `parse-primes` nested function. After applying these, the code will be much cleaner, and you can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

First, is there a reason why you do a `(parse-primes (rest lines))` instead of `(parse-primes lines)` at the end ? it produces an exception when your input `String` contains only 1 value, e.g. `"6"`.

Then, as @ntalbs suggests you should segregate a bit the concern in each of your functions. Keeping the idea of your algorithm, you can have `parse-primes` generate a infinite sequence of primes instead of printing and recurring on input :

```
(parse-primes []
              (filter #(is-prime? %) (iterate inc 2)))
```

Then add a specific function to get the Nth prime :

```
(nth-prime [n]
           (nth (parse-primes) n))
```

You can then replace the main part of `work` function `(parse-primes lines)` by `(map nth-prime lines)`, which makes this function return a sequence instead of printing as a side effect and returning `nil`.

As a matter of cleaning you can remove the input parsing of `work` to match the now returned sequence :

```
(defn work [rank-of-primes]
  (letfn [...]
    (map nth-prime rank-of-primes)))

(let [ranks-of-primes (map read-string (str/split-lines input))]
  (work ranks-of-primes))
```

Now just to improve performance you can test only odd numbers and the number `2` in `is-prime?` and simplify with the use of `not-any?`.

```
(is-prime? [n]
           (not-any? #(= 0 (mod n %)) 
                     (cons 2 (range 3 (inc (Math/sqrt n)) 2)))
```

At this point, without modifying the algo you chose, it should be a little bit cleaner :

```
(defn work [rank-of-primes]
  (letfn [(is-prime? [n]
                     (not-any? #(= 0 (mod n %)) 
                               (cons 2 (range 3 (inc (Math/sqrt n)) 2))))
          (parse-primes []
                        (cons 2 (filter #(is-prime? %) 
                                (cons 2 (iterate (partial + 2) 3)))))
          (nth-prime [n]
                     (nth (parse-primes) n))]
    (map nth-prime rank-of-primes)))

(let [input "2\n3\n6\n10000"
      ranks-of-primes (map read-string (str/split-lines input))]
  (work ranks-of-primes))
```

There is a lot to explore in the matter of primes. If you have interest in primes algos in Clojure, this [blog post](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/index.php?s=eratosthenes) from C.Grand is more involved.

Comment: The program that checks the answer checks STDOUT so that is why I did it that way.

Comment: Did the answer help in anyway ?

Comment: it did help to clean up the code but I never got the problem finishing fast enough, I blogged about the experience here http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/02/07/primes/